# ember-simple-auth custom authorizer not called with ember-django-adpter

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using ember-django-adapter with ember-simple-auth and have written the custom authorizer for token authentication. I am able to obtain the token from server but not able to inject it into the api requests using the adapter.

app/authorizers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default Base.extend({

  session: service('session'),

  init: function () {
    console.log('Intialize authorizer');
  },

  authorize(data, block) {
    const accessToken = data['access_token'];
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
      block('Authorization', `Token ${accessToken}`);
      console.log("authorizer called with token: " + accessToken);
    }
  }
});
```

app/adapters/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DRFAdapter from 'ember-django-adapter/adapter/drf';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

const { service } = Ember.inject;

export default DRFAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  session: service('session'),
  authorizer: 'authorizer:application'

});
```

app/authenticators/token.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';

export default Base.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/ember-auth/',

  authenticate: function(email, password) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: this.serverTokenEndpoint,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Got token: ' + response.token);

        Ember.run(function() {
          resolve({
            token: response.token
          });
        });
      }, function(xhr) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        Ember.run(function() {
          reject(response);
        });
      });
    });
  },

  invalidate: function() {
    console.log('invalidate...');
    return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
  }
});
```

Ember tries to transition to protected route but due to non injection of Authorization header the request fails with 403 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I use OAuth2BearerAuthorizer in ember-simple-auth in conjunction with django-oauth-toolkit and have had good success.  Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: Yes but ember simple auth forces you to hard code client id and secret in config which essentially is public which defeats the whole purpose

Comment: Ember is a public client, so the client credentials don't matter much.  It's the resource owner credentials (username and password) that matter.

Comment: Here's a conversation I had on this topic with other ember-simple-auth users: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/226#issuecomment-47423329

Comment: Marcoow's response later in the same thread: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/226#issuecomment-52302731

Comment: That conversation was almost 2 years ago.  The long and short of it is that while OAuth2 is geared more towards private clients, the specification does allow for public clients and today's ember-simple-auth supports that.  I recommend it for Django projects because django-oauth-toolkit is so easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am already using djano-oauth-toolkit for the internal api but each application that is created using oauth toolkit is tied to a user. While in case of public client (eg. ember) the application in oauth cannot be used for more than one user. Does it make sense? Apologies if I am unable to explain clearly.